# Random Django TemplateDoesNotExist Errors

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, race-condition, django-endless-pagination

I have a Django site in production running Django 1.2.5 using Python 2.7/mod_wsgi 3.3. For the most part everything works great, but it seems that the site is throwing errors totally at random. They all end in the form:

TemplateDoesNotExist: xxx

These templates definitely do exist, and when I type in the URL that caused the exception the URL always seems to work. However, once in approximately every 30 page views, this error is thrown.

I found this post about a similar problem: http://leequerv.blogspot.com/2009/11/re-settingspy-seems-to-be-cached-or_24.html but I am only running one Django application so it doesn't seem to apply directly.

I am using some subdomain middleware that swaps template directories depending on the subdomain of my site (i.e. it uses the regular template dirs if there is no subdomain, and uses my mobile template dirs if it has an m.xxx subdomain). All of this works great, both on my dev server and on the production server, except for these sporadic production server errors. Is it possible this is creating a race condition when lots of people are using the site?

Do you have any ideas what could be causing it or where I should begin looking?

**Edit:**

Here is the part of the middleware code where the template directories are switched:

```
    subdomain = getattr(request, 'subdomain', False)

    if subdomain is not False:
        try:
            request.urlconf = settings.SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS[subdomain]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.SUBDOMAIN_TEMPLATE_DIRS[subdomain]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Here is the part of my settings file that holds the template dir info:

`SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
        None: 'my_site.urls',
        'm': 'mobile.urls'
    }`

```
JQM_TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates/mobile/"),
)

SUBDOMAIN_TEMPLATE_DIRS = {
    None: TEMPLATE_DIRS,
    'm': JQM_TEMPLATE_DIRS
}
```

**Edit #2**:

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/my_username/python-environments/my_site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/endless_pagination/decorators.py", line 55, in decorated
   return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/my_site/local_apps/team/views.py", line 68, in team_detail
   return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/lib/python2.7/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 20, in render_to_response
   return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader.py", line 181, in render_to_string
   t = get_template(template_name)

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
   template, origin = find_template(template_name)

 File "/home/my_username/webapps/my_site/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
   raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

TemplateDoesNotExist: team_detail.html
```

Comment: when this exception is Raise do you get an error page , or the page is still render ? if it's the second choice so maybe and i'm just guessing here that it's the django cache (if you use one of course) that may throw this error when it don't find the template in the cache (because of cache timeout or what so ever) and then get the template from the file system to render it, so it work but it show the error because of cache MISS !?

Comment: May we have a more elaborate traceback please?

Comment: When the exception is raised the application crashes, and my server displays a default 500 Internal Server Error page. It does not even give the normal django 500.html page because it can't find that template directory.

Comment: As for the cache... I currently don't use any cache so it isn't because of a cache miss.

Comment: is it possible to see the code of the middleware where the template dirs get switched ?

Comment: Yep, I just added the middleware code and the code from settings.py

Comment: @pyeleven I just added my traceback. Sorry for not being more descriptive earlier.

Comment: i had same exact problem with shared hosting and django 0.97 a while ago, never found the cause and users never complained, so i gave up :)

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks for letting me know but I'd be sad if I didn't find the cause. I'd assume those random errors are pretty annoying as a user :(

Comment: I suspect there is an issue with modifying the settings.  If you're using a multi-process  server it *should* be fine, but using green threads (or possibly threads, though I'm not 100% on this) you may run into an issue as the settings are global.  There are few possible workarounds I can think of:  1) The accepted answer below (yuck)  2) roll your own template finder that's subdomain-aware 3) roll your own render function that can dynamically modify the TEMPLATE_DIR locally (yuck).  I think (2) would be your best bet if feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remedy this problem, I removed all of the logic that involved swapping the paths to the template directories. My guess is that when the python paths were getting changed for the system, other concurrent requests were sometimes seeing the wrong set of python paths.

Thus, I just gave the mobile site and the regular site access to the same paths to the template directories and made sure there were no conflicting templates with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the uwsgi configuration (uwsgi.ini). Still don't know why but hopefully will help someone else.

Adding the following parameters fixed my problem:

```
disable-logging = True

max-worker-lifetime = 600
```